# How to get window "right"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to position a floating tooltip on my webpage, and I want it so that if the tooltip is going to hang over the right edge of the window, it should flip it around the other way. Here's what I've got:

```
$('[data-tooltip]').mousemove(function(e) {
    var left = e.pageX + 1;
    if(left + $kewtip.outerWidth() > ?????) {
        left = e.pageX - $kewtip.outerWidth() - 1;
    }
    var top = e.pageY - $kewtip.outerHeight() - 1;
    $kewtip.css({
        left: left,
        top: top
    });
});
```

I don't know what to fill in for the question-marks. `left + $kewtip.outerWidth()` should give me the right edge of the tooltip, and I want to check if that's greater than the right edge of the window.

`$(window).width()` won't work, particularly when you've scrolled horizontally a bit.

Comment: What about `.innerWidth`

Comment: You could use `$(window).width()` with `$(window).scrollLeft()` to figure out the position. just the width would work normally but if you're scrolled right on the page, you need to add the scroll left to it to account for that.

Comment: window.width + scrollLeft should do the trick, I think.

Comment: haha three people same comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding in the scroll position?

```
$(window).width() + $(document).scrollLeft()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can use jQuery UI but there is a Position utility that you can use to do this.  The utility has a property called `collision` that, in your case, could be set to `flip` to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Yeah, but it's only like 15 lines of code. Not sure I want a plugin for that.